# How do i send template to user where user can edit pdf and all textbox and checkbox comes placed inline

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am trying to send user a template pdf where all the fields are pre populated with textbox and check box. How do i do that?

Comment: Search for `pdf fillable form`.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign doesn't allow you to change the PDF document itself but any tabs that you add to the document can be set/updated via the API.

I included some info on how you can check/un-check check-ox tabs and how you could pre-populate the text in a textTab.

I hope this helps!

Checkboxes can be checked/un-checked using the selected property in the API:

```
"checkboxTabs": [
    {
      "name": "sample string 1",
      "tabLabel": "sample string 2",
      "selected": "sample string 3",
      "shared": "sample string 4",
      "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "sample string 5",
      "required": "sample string 6",
      "locked": "sample string 7",
      "documentId": "sample string 8",
      "recipientId": "sample string 9",
      "pageNumber": "sample string 10",
      "xPosition": "sample string 11",
      "yPosition": "sample string 12",
      "anchorString": "sample string 13",
      "anchorXOffset": "sample string 14",
      "anchorYOffset": "sample string 15",
      "anchorUnits": "sample string 16",
      "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "sample string 17",
      "anchorCaseSensitive": "sample string 18",
      "anchorMatchWholeWord": "sample string 19",
      "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "sample string 20",
      "tabId": "sample string 21",
      "templateLocked": "sample string 22",
      "templateRequired": "sample string 23",
      "conditionalParentLabel": "sample string 24",
      "conditionalParentValue": "sample string 25",
      "customTabId": "sample string 26",
      "mergeField": {},
      "status": "sample string 27",
      "tooltip": "sample string 28",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      },
      "tabOrder": "sample string 29",
      "tabGroupLabels": [
        "sample string 1"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

For textTabs you can pre-fill the textTab using the value property via the API:

```
"textTabs": [
    {
      "height": 1,
      "isPaymentAmount": "sample string 2",
      "formula": "sample string 3",
      "validationPattern": "sample string 4",
      "validationMessage": "sample string 5",
      "shared": "sample string 6",
      "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "sample string 7",
      "senderRequired": "sample string 8",
      "requireAll": "sample string 9",
      "name": "sample string 10",
      "value": "sample string 11",
      "originalValue": "sample string 12",
      "width": 13,
      "required": "sample string 14",
      "locked": "sample string 15",
      "concealValueOnDocument": "sample string 16",
      "disableAutoSize": "sample string 17",
      "maxLength": 18,
      "tabLabel": "sample string 19",
      "font": "sample string 20",
      "bold": "sample string 21",
      "italic": "sample string 22",
      "underline": "sample string 23",
      "fontColor": "sample string 24",
      "fontSize": "sample string 25",
      "documentId": "sample string 26",
      "recipientId": "sample string 27",
      "pageNumber": "sample string 28",
      "xPosition": "sample string 29",
      "yPosition": "sample string 30",
      "anchorString": "sample string 31",
      "anchorXOffset": "sample string 32",
      "anchorYOffset": "sample string 33",
      "anchorUnits": "sample string 34",
      "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "sample string 35",
      "anchorCaseSensitive": "sample string 36",
      "anchorMatchWholeWord": "sample string 37",
      "anchorHorizontalAlignment": "sample string 38",
      "tabId": "sample string 39",
      "templateLocked": "sample string 40",
      "templateRequired": "sample string 41",
      "conditionalParentLabel": "sample string 42",
      "conditionalParentValue": "sample string 43",
      "customTabId": "sample string 44",
      "mergeField": {},
      "status": "sample string 45",
      "tooltip": "sample string 46",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
        "message": ""
      },
      "tabOrder": "sample string 47",
      "tabGroupLabels": [
        "sample string 1"
      ]
    }
  ],
```